# A way to detect Platforms on Trigger.io

Tags: trigger.io

Is there a way to detect what platform the app is running on with Javascript in trigger.io? It looks like in the olden days there was an is.android and is.ios method that have since disappeared. We have some different behaviors we want to apply to the different browsers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the `forge.is` namespace allows you to detect the platform using JavaScript.

To detect if the app is running on an Android device call `forge.is.android()`

To detect if the app is running on an iOS device call `forge.is.ios()`

See the [Platform Detection](https://trigger.io/docs/current/api/core/is.html) docs for more information.

Comment: I couldn't find that documentation to save my life. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

depending on your needs there are a few answers.

The isAndroid or isIOS can work for detecting simply the device but will not give you the version number, somtimes you need to detect versions of IOS or android.

To do that you should use the platform module

https://trigger.io/modules/platform/current/docs/index.html