# Is it required that I use forge.request.ajax in stead of $.post?

Tags: trigger.io

First , I am not trying to do a cross site request.

I have created a small JS app and I can test in in a browser and it works fine i.

I see that my request from the app makes it to my server and I can confirm that my server responds with the data I expect. The problem is that the compiled app triggers the .fail in my javascript.

Is is REQUIRED that I use forge.request.ajax. instead of $.post? I see many posts saying I should but no one says I cannot use $.post .It makes debugging and development much easier being able to test all my JS in a browser before making the package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately I haven't found a way around it. You can use a [promise](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q), create a wrapper function/service, detect the [platform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23965415/a-way-to-detect-platforms-on-trigger-io) that you are running on and call the corresponding function.